# A set A is compact, is its boundary compact?

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

I am trying to understand the concept of a boundary, and I have seen it defined  $Bd(A) = \overline{A} \cap \overline{A^{\complement}}$. I was wondering three things, First how can I show that the boundary of a compact set is compact. I want to try proving with the definition above. I feel as thought it is one of those things that is inherently true but hard to prove, I know that if A is compact, it must be bounded, thus anything it intersects with is bounded, but what about the situation where A closure is not bounded.

There other two things I was wondering about was can you have a boundary that is the empty set, and a boundary that is the real numbers. For the empty set I was thinking 1/n plus 0, would produce a set that has a boundary of the empty set, not sure about the reals tho.

Comment: I see that you've tagged this "real-analysis", but I'd caution you about conflating results from compact sets in real spaces (e.g. from [Heine-Borel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem)) and topological definitions.

Answer (score 11):

**postscript:** I was a bit hasty.  In a Hausdorff space, compact sets are closed. **end of postscript**

Being closed [but see above], compact sets contain all of their boundary points. The boundary of a compact set is therefore a subset of that compact set and is closed.  Closed subsets of compact sets are compact.

Comment: "Compact sets are closed" requires that the space be Hausdorff.  However, I can't think of a non-Hausdorff counterexample to the claim itself.

Comment: Got one: the particular point topology.  Let $X$ be an infinite set with a distinguished point $p$ and define the topology $\tau$ consisting of the empty set and all subsets that contain $p$.  Then $A := \{p\}$ is open and compact, $\bar{A} = X$, and so $\partial A = X \setminus A$.  This is not compact since $\{ \{p,x\} : x \ne p\}$ is an infinite open cover of $X \setminus A$ with no proper subcover.

Comment: Well, the OP used the 'real-analysis' tag, so we might suppose that he was talking about the real numbers.

Comment: @NateEldredge For a T$_1$ counterexample, take $(\mathbb Z,\tau)$ where $\tau=\{U\subseteq\mathbb Z:U=\emptyset\text{ or }\mathbb N\setminus U\text{ is finite}\}$; then $\mathbb N$ is compact while $\partial\mathbb N=\mathbb Z\setminus\mathbb N$ is an infinite discrete space.

Answer (score 2):

About the rest of the question, which has been skipped by Michael, a set with empty boundary is necessarily open and closed (because its closure is itself, and the closure of its complelent is the complement itself). So in R the only sets with empty boundary are the empty set and R itself.

On the other side, a set with the whole R as booundary is easy, just take any dense and co-dense set, like the rationals. Being dense, its closure is all R, and as the complement is dense too, then the boundary is actually R.